# Reply to all cc'ed - Mail OSX

Tags: macos, mail.app, email

When I receive an email which has been cc'ed to a few people, is there a way where  I can set the default reply mode to *"reply to all"*, rather than *"reply to just the sender"*?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are using the Mail application by Apple.
In this case, you just need to press the "double arrow" button, rather than the "single arrow", to reply to all the senders, as you can see here:

[image]

Otherwise, you can use the shortcut <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to perform the same "reply to all" operation.

Comment: Thanks, id been using the icon version but sometime i just automaticly click on the reply to sender only, i was wandering if there was a way to make the reply to all the default

Comment: Have you tried with the shortcut? I think this can be the only way you can always reply to all senders automatically (if you sometimes pick the wrong button).